# Editing Instance Attributes in Python

Tags: python, class, instance

I have a python class called Player that looks like this ...

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
         self.display = 'A'
         self.num_water_buckets = 0
         self.row = 0
         self.col = 0
```

I am having trouble editing the self.row and self.col ... maybe they're immutable but I haven't found much of this on the internet. `Player().row` and `Player().col` work, however they print 0 every time. I am trying to edit them using `Player().row = value` where value is a variable containing a number.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Okay so I understand that you have to define a new occurrence of this instance using x = Player() then x.row = ...

But I need to originally initialise the variable with certain values (which are different every time) so I thought I could use a function and the return value from that function would set the initial value from the variable but it just creates an infinite recursion.
I did...

```
class Player:
def __init__(self):
    from game_parser import read_lines
    self.display = 'A'
    self.num_water_buckets = 0
    self.row = Player().detRow(sys.argv[1])
    self.col = Player().detCol(sys.argv[1])

def detRow(fileName):
    # use this function to return the row
def detCol(fileName):
    # use this function to return the col
```

Comment: Also I know there are other ways to do this like passing the variable in like def __init__(self, variable) then self.row = variable. Or something like that but it has to follow this structure

Comment: You have not shown how you are trying to "edit the self.row and self.col".

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to do it using Player().row = value where value is a variable containing a number

Comment: `Player()` is created each time, it's not the same object you retrieve the next time.  You need to give it a name to have the same reference back to the same object.  i.e. `player = Player(); player.row = 1`.  When you retrieve `player.row` next time it will return `1`.

Comment: Okay I understand this now, thank you, but I still need to change the initial value of it, if that makes sense. I updated the question that explains it a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
Player().row = value
print(Player().row)
```

The `Player()` in the first row creates a new instance; then you modify it by setting its `row` attribute to `value`; then you throw away that instance, because you haven't bothered to remember it anywhere. Then in the next row, you create a *new* instance (where the initialiser sets the `row` attribute to zero).

Not all players are interchangeable. If you sit John in the second row, it does not mean Harry will be in the second row too; it just means John is in the second row.

To do it correctly, store your `Player` instance in a variable:

```
john = Player()
john.row = 2
print(john.row)
```

Comment: oh okay that makes so much sense, you have to define a particular "instance" (occurrence) of the variables in the constructor. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite. 1) variables don't have instances, classes do; variables can _contain_ or _refer to_ instances (of classes). 2) your code does not have a constructor (`__new__`) — `__init__` is an initialiser, as the name says; 3) none of what I said above (except setting the initial value of the attribute to zero) happens in initialiser (or constructor).

Comment: Ok okay, I'm confusing this with class attributes. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add put the variable outside the `__init__()` method

EDIT: added row and col to the class

```py
class Player:
    row = 0 # NO self here
    col = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.display = 'A'
        self.num_water_buckets = 0

john = Player()
john.num_water_buckets = 12

print(f'before change: {john.col}')
john.col = 5
print(f'after change: {john.col}')
print(f'class property: {Player.col}') # note it did not change the class
```

Output:

```
before change: 0
after change: 5
class property: 0
```

Comment: Okay thank you. I am just confused because they want the row and col to be stored like that in the class (not as a separate instance) so I might have to set it equal to a function that returns the row and col or something. But thanks for the help :)

Comment: to define a "constant" variable for the class, move it out of the `__init__` method, I'll update